# Gleason Yamabe for groupoids

Tags: lie-groups, groupoids, lie-groupoids

A colleague of mine seems convinced that there is a Gleason-Yamabe type theorem for locally compact groupoids. Does anyone know if this is true? If so, any references would be most appreciated.

Comment: Does he have a precise conjecture?

Comment: No, he does not. I was curious if there were any results along the lines of: Let $G$ be a locally compact groupoid and let $U\subset G$ be a neighborhood of the identity arrows ($G^0$). Does there exist an (open?) subgroupoid $G'$ of $K$ and a proper continuous groupoid homomorphism  $\phi:G'\to H$ where $H$ is a Lie groupoid and for which the preimage of each identity arrow in $H$ is contained in $U$?  I am not really in love with this formulation, but do you see what I am asking?

Comment: To be honest, I am partly interested in what the exact formulation of a Gleason-Yamabe theorem for locally compact groupoids would be. For example, is it true that a proper locally compact groupoid that is connected (in some sense or another) is an inverse limit of Lie groupoids?